# struct array making strange run error C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to run this code, and i get run time error in any of those commands:

```
strcpy( memories[i].name, "file");
            memories[i].name[4]=i+48;
            memories[i].name[5]='\0';
```

I tried to understand the reason for this for quite long time but can't find it. especially when this command works:

```
strcpy( mm.name, "working file");
```

the full code:

```
struct Memory {
   char  name[50]; //the name of the file
   char  storage[8000]; //the storage of the file
   uint32_t address;
   int   sizeInUse; //bytes that are used
   int   memory_id; 
};

//void initialMemory (struct Memory mm, struct Memory memories[]);


    struct Memory mm; //working file
    struct Memory memories[10];
    //initialMemory ( mm ,memories);
    strcpy( mm.name, "working file");
    mm.address=&mm.storage;
    mm.memory_id=-1;
    mm.sizeInUse=0;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        strcpy( memories[i].name, "file");
        memories[i].name[4]=i+48;
        memories[i].name[5]='\0';
        memories[i].address= &memories[i].storage;
        memories[i].memory_id=i;
        int index=(i+1)*2; //we will fill (i+1)*200 places of memory i.
        memories[i].sizeInUse= index;
        for(j=0; j<index; j++){
            memories[i].storage[j]=j+48;
        }
        memories[i].storage[index+1]='~';
    }
```

Comment: dont use uint32_t to store an address. It is not portable and thats what pointers are for.

Comment: `mm.address=&mm.storage;` is an error. A pointer cannot be assigned to an integer. If you don't get a compiler error message then adjust your compiler settings.

Comment: "*the full code*" well ...

Comment: @M.M , I tried to remove this field and I still get the same problem. it's C for embedded system and it lead me to this break point (error):
`void Default_Handler()`

`{`
`__asm("bkpt");`
`}`

Comment: @Osiris , see please the above comment

Comment: @Mr.OY: What are you trying to achieve? What is the outcome?
One problem i see is that `memories[i].storage[j]=j+48;` doesnt put in the correct numbers for `j >= 10`, also you should not use magic numbers. The next thing is that `memories[i].storage[index+1]='~'` doesnt terminate your string, maybe you dont want a 0 terminated string, but it depends on further use of this array.

Comment: @Osiris, I'm writing a code for microcontroller, and what I'm trying to achieve is being able to create blocks of memory in the SRAM which will hold strings. the code here was for creating those arrays with just some unique initialization. the char '~' is a symbol for me just like EOF, and not the terminate my string which maybe next time will more space for the strings (I know it's stupid way to manage it because of the unused memory space, but i'm short in time for doing it).
As I see it and tried, those problems you mentioned don't should do an error as I get. Am I wrong? thank you